# Highlight search terms on found page

Tags: html, search-engine

I am using a Google Custom Search Engine ([link](https://www.google.com/cse/) and [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element)) to provide a site search for my website. For now I have a poorly styled `<gcse:searchbox-only>` on my main site; this pops open the results.  (At some point I'd like to use the `<gcse:searchresults-only>` on a separate page.

However, because some of the pages shown in the result list are rather lengthy, I wonder if there is a way to click on a search result link and highlight the matching text on the target page?  I don't want to highlight the search terms on the result list, but rather on the target page a user selects from the Google result list.

How would I go about this?

**EDIT:** Here is an example of what I mean. Use Google to search for *"man strcpy"* ([click](http://www.google.com.au/search?q=man%20strcpy)) and the first search result should be at linux.die.net. When I click on that link, it'll take me to the website and highlight both *"man"* and *"strcpy"* on that target page. Is works when using Google, Bing, Yahoo.

Answer (score 0):

From a quick scan of the [docs](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) I see that you can use either the `data-queryParameterName` *or* `queryParameterName`, with the value 'search' to pass the search term/phrase to your results page.  You could then get the query string and pass it along.

Once the user clicks from the results list to the intended page, you'd have the query available and could highlight the results.

Comment: It sounds like this would require some explicit support on the website's end to receive values from the link clicked on the results page? Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: From what I can tell initially, yes.  Google will pass the search term/phrase as a query to the results page only.  If those results links *also* contain the search query the you only need to parse the query on the final page.  If not, you'll need to parse the query string on the results page and pass to final page via session, cookies, etc.

Comment: First thing I would do is add the attribute to your markup, and see how Google passes that query.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that this week. I just realized that I'll have to `<span>` the search terms as well, in order to be able to highlight them. More to do on the server side when a page is called from a search results site...